# Embed graphical editor to a web page

Tags: html, web, 3d, frameworks, web-component

I am creating a web page and I need to add a component that allows a user who enters my web to graphically edit an 3d model in order to create custom designs using a GUI.
Paint, add shapes, colors, images ...

I have searched on google and I don't see anything, do you know if there is any framework that allows me this for either 3d or 2d models?

For example:

I want to add a GUI on my website similar to the orange square
[image: example 3d model gui editor]

I would be grateful for anything to start at least.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To edit an image is much easier than a 3D model. You should use the canvas element to edit images. See https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp. You draw everything you want using javascript and save it as PNG, JPG or webhp.

Answer (score 1):

Search again, there is plenty of options around:

**[google.com/search?q=online+image+editor+github](https://google.com/search?q=online+image+editor+github)**

- http://viliusle.github.io/miniPaint/
- https://www.photopea.com/
- https://scaleflex.github.io/filerobot-image-editor/
- and loads more

Your challenge is to try them all and then make it work the way you want.